# VisualC++ 6.0 with unsigned long long and sprintf

Tags: c, visual-c++-6

I want to sprintf() an unsigned long long value in visual C++ 6.0 (plain C).

```
char buf[1000]; //bad coding 
unsigned __int64 l = 12345678; 
char t1[6] = "test1"; 
char t2[6] = "test2"; 
sprintf(buf, "%lli, %s, %s", l, t1, t2);
```

gives the result

```
12345678, (null), test1
```

(watch that `test2` is not printed)

and `l = 123456789012345` it gives an exception handle

any suggestions?

Comment: sorry, i was ungenau.

    char buf[1000]; //bad coding
    unsigned __int64 l = 12345678;
    char t[5] = "test";

    sprintf(buf, "%lli, %s", l, t);

gives the result
    12345678. (null)

and l = 123456789012345 it gives an exception handle

Comment: @Lytha Alexander, you should edit your question and add this to the question rather than adding it in a comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To print an `unsigned __int64` value in Visual C++ 6.0 you should use `%I64u`, not `%lli` (refer to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272936%28VS.60%29.aspx) on MSDN). `%lli` is only supported in Visual Studio 2005 and later versions.
So, your code should be:

```
sprintf(buf, "%I64u, %s, %s", l, t1, t2);
```

Answer (score 1):

printf uses the ellipsis to pass a variable argument list. The (null) you see is the second part of your long long, which happen to be all 0 bits. Set it to 1<<60+1<<30 and you'll get a crash as the 1<<60 part is interpreted as a char*.

The correct solution would be to break down the number in three parts of 10 digits, "verylongvalue % 10000000000" "(verylongvalue/10000000000) % 10000000000" "verylongvalue/100000000000000000000".

Answer (score -1):

Apparently, you did not assign `additionaltext` to the necessary `char *` (string). Note that the `long int` was processed, the comma was copied and only the `%s` generated `(null)`.